# Binding query result column alias in SQL Server

Tags: c#, sql-server, visual-studio-2010, data-binding

I've been binding database columns to controls in Visual Studio 2010 by dragging column names from Data Sources onto the form designer.

I have a query that looks like:

```
SELECT BankId, CASE WHEN (ProductId = 1) THEN 'True' ELSE 'False' END AS Prod1Avail
FROM tblBankProducts
WHERE (CompanyId = @CompanyId)
```

`Prod1Avail` isn't shown in Data Sources. How is one supposed to bind the column alias (`Prod1Avail`) from a query to a control using Visual Studio's Designer?

Thanks

Comment: You can perform the binding pro grammatically instead of using the designer for this purpose.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT     BankId, CAST(CASE WHEN (ProductId = 1) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS bit) AS Prod1Avail
FROM         tblBankProducts
WHERE     (CompanyId = @CompanyId)
```

[Update the query](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kda44dwy.aspx) of TableAdapter as below.

1. Select a TableAdapter in the component tray.
2. Click the TableAdapter's smart tag, and choose Add Query.
3. Complete the dialog box with above query